# Extends react component from parent class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

im using react starter kit, im try to extends react component from parent class and it work, but the problem is hot reload, hot reload wont work if i do that..

this is my parent class..

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
export default class Core extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        console.log("INIT");
    }
}
```

and this is my main class..

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PageHeader from 'react-bootstrap/lib/PageHeader';
import Core from '../core';


export default class AdsEvent extends Core {
    constructor(){
        super();
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-lg-12">
                        <PageHeader>Ads Event</PageHeader>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

when i change some text on pageheader, console return this message..

[HMR] The following modules couldn't be hot updated: (Full reload needed)
This is usually because the modules which have changed (and their parents) do not know how to hot reload themselves.

Comment: I think it would be better to opt for [composition over inheritance](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) in this case.